# CA2213 triggers when using null conditional operator in dispose pattern

Tags: c#, dispose, static-analysis

I am working on a code base that considers static code analysis design warnings as errors.

When I implement my Dispose() method like this:

```
public void Dispose()
{
     threadPool?.Dispose();
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

The error I get

> error CA1063: Microsoft.Design : Modify 'HandlerBase.Dispose()' so
> that it calls Dispose(true), then calls GC.SuppressFinalize on the
> current object instance ('this' or 'Me' in Visual Basic), and then
> returns.

So I modify it to follow the pattern expected by CA1063

```
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
     if (disposed)
     {
         return;
     }

     if (disposing)
     {
         threadPool?.Dispose();
     }

     disposed = true;
}

 public void Dispose()
{
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
 }
```

And it no longer realizes that I'm disposing the object:

> error CA2213: Microsoft.Usage : 'HandlerBase' contains field
> 'HandlerBase.threadPool' that is of IDisposable type: 'SemaphoreSlim'.
> Change the Dispose method on 'HandlerBase' to call Dispose or Close on
> this field.

Comment: maybe its getting confused by the null conditional ? remove it and see if you still get the error

Comment: @00110001 that was it! thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suspected, it seems to be a bug with the Roslyn Analyser.

[CA2213 triggers when using null conditional operator #291](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/291)

It seems to be fixed in later versions (if I read correctly); however, if that is not applicable to you, or it's still not working you can suppress the warning/error or just remove the null conditional and check for null manually:

```
if(threadPool != null)
   threadPool.Dispose();
```